# Configure Spring Gateway to forward web requests to internal url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I have Spring Gateway application with the following Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
implementation 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

Route configuration:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, LoggingGatewayFilterFactory loggingFactory) {

    return builder.routes()
            .route("service_route_clients_summary", r -> r.path("c")
                    .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/api/management/home/clients/summary", "/management/home/clients/summary")
                            .filter(loggingFactory.apply(new LoggingGatewayFilterFactory.Config("My Custom Message", true, true))))
                    .uri("lb://merchant-hub-admin-service:8000/management/home/clients/summary"))
            .build();
}
```

I want to forward `/api/management/home/clients/summary` to internal link `/management/home/clients/summary` but using Eureka client to find the internal service.

When I rung the code nothing happened - path is not found.
Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eureka discovery you could do something like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          lowerCaseServiceId: true
          enabled: true
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                pattern: "'/api/'+serviceId.toLowerCase()+'/**'"
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "'/api/' + serviceId.toLowerCase() + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
                replacement: "'/${remaining}'"
```

Ofcourse you will need `@EnableDiscoveryClient` in your main class.
If interested, could look into one of my [test repos](https://github.com/dhananjay12/spring-microservice-demo).

In eureka check /eureka/app and see metadata for your service. You will see if the service has a context path or not. If it does not, above configuration will work.

If the service do have a contextPath, you need to use folowwing in `replacement` key:

```
replacement: "{metadata.get('contextPath') != null ? metadata.get('contextPath') : ''} + '/${remaining}'"
```

Comment: I get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://1.1.1.1.1.15:8080/api/merchants/onboarding/countries' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.` This is for GET request

Comment: Is the downstream service also setting cors headers?

Comment: No, it's working fine. I have added there this cors configuration: https://pastebin.com/DKqcgSjt

Comment: Isnt the question about routing to an internal service, that is registered in Eureka?

Comment: I guess, this CORS question is something else you asked in another post

Comment: Correct, my mistake. Can you show me how to do the above configuration using Java code?

Comment: If your service(management) is already registered to Eureka, the discovery client along with spring cloud gateway OOTB filters should be the approach. You can look into their codebase if you like.
If the management service has a context path, and thats why you are willing to write your own router function?

Comment: In eureka check /eureka/app and see metadata for your service. You will see if the service has a context path or not. If it does not, above configuration will work.

Comment: If it does contain a contextPath - check the second option, I will update the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can add filter expression which will trim the url as per your requirement.

Below config will make url as /api/management ==> /management

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: rewritepath_route
        uri: https://example.org
        predicates:
        - Path=/api/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/api(?<segment>/?.*), /$\{segment}
```

Comment: Can you show me Java configuration please?

Answer (score 1):

Short version, the arguments you're passing into routes().route aren't correct.

You should try something like this:

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path(" /api/management/home/clients/summary **")
                        .filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec
                                .rewritePath("/management/home/clients/summary/(?<remaining>.*)"
                                , "/home/clients//${remaining}"))
                        .uri("lb:///home/clients/summary/"))
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that I don't need to specify the target service like this: `.uri("lb://merchant-hub-admin-service/merchants/onboarding/business_structure"))`?

Comment: Full code: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Spring_Cloud_Gateway_POC

Comment: Are you sure that I don't need to specify the target service?

Comment: I tested the code but I get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://1.1.1.1.1:8080/api/support/tickets/severity_levels' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.